# How do I shutdown Teamcity?

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to do a password reset. I'm following the [instructions here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Changing+user+password+with+default+authentication+scheme). I've tried shutting down the two services (TeamCity Build Agent Service and TeamCity Web Server) or some combination of the two, but I keep getting "User with specified username does not exist".

Is there something else I need to stop or shutdown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is an issue on the TeamCity side, it's more likely that the error message is correct - the username doesn't exist. The steps you're following look fine, have you double / triple / quadruple checked the username is spot on? Maybe also check whether you can change the password for other user names and see if it's an isolated problem or not.

Comment: Yeah, I found out that the username was set to domain\username so you're right.

Answer (score 11):

Shut down TeamCity via the command in its `bin` directory:

```
D:\TeamCity\bin\shutdown.bat
```

Comment: And how to you Start it back up afterward?

Comment: @Suamere - Well, a bit late, but in the same bin directory, there is startup.bat

Answer (score 4):

I can't reply to suamere's comment but just like the shutdown script there is a startup script in the bin folder, e.g.

D:\TeamCity\bin\startup.bat

Answer (score 2):

in the Teamcity/bin directory run the following

```
./teamcity-server.sh stop
```

Comment: FYI, this is usually located at `/opt/JetBrains/TeamCity/bin/`