# How can I find out the list of users in TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity

I have RDP access to the server, and I want to ensure that I've got the right username (for this: [How do I shutdown Teamcity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731600/how-do-i-shutdown-teamcity)).

Is there a command line way of viewing the registered users, like there is for changing a password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TeamCity users are stored inside the TeamCity Database, I would suggest you migrate your teamcity Installation to an external Database such as MSSQL Server, or MySQL.  You will get improved stability and performance, and you will be able to access the users table directly to see the usernames.

Please see this guide for migrating TeamCity to an external Database
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Setting+up+an+External+Database